# Iterating through two Lists and checking the item value of the first list to the item values of the second list with a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

So in the program I'm trying to run I receive two lists, one with objects that contain an id in string format (looks something like "bb_b1203322") and one list with the id's(which in this place is only named "b1203322" for reasons unknown) and a description of the actually id's meaning.

```
var forms = await _tRepository.GetAllFormsAsync(lastUpdate);
var formDefinitions = await _deRepository.GetAllFormDefintionsAsync();

foreach (var form in forms)
{
    foreach (var def in formDefinitions)
    {
        if (form.SetupFormName.Contains(def.BLKID))
            form.SetupFormName = def.DESCR;
    }
}
return forms;
```

Now this piece of code does exactly what I want it to, but I'd rather have it as a lambda expression because ... reasons :)

Now I've tried several different things but with my current knowledge of lambda expressions I can't get it to work.

Comment: By "with lambda expressions" are you expecting a single *statement*? And what exact reasons are you talking about? I could see using a `Where` on the inner loop to avoid the `if`, but that's about all I'd do...

Comment: Only if it's possible I'm not an unreasonable man :)

Comment: what reasons? I'm trying to think of a good one.

Comment: Reasons: I'm trying to shorten down the code from several different rows, but I also think that it may be useful knowledge in the future for something a little more complex than this?

Comment: My question though is why do you want to convert to foreach? but if thy insist checkout this article.
 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/549567/Howplustoplusconvertplusnormalplusforeachplusloopp

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a bit of LINQ to find the definition:

```
foreach(var form in forms)
{
    var def = formDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(x => form.SetupFormName.Contains(x.DESCR));
    if(def != null)
        form.SetupFormName = def.DESCR
}
```

As you can see, it's not really saving all that much code.

Please note:
As Jon correctly comments, the behavior of this code is a bit different from your original one. This code uses the first occurrence if there are multiple and your code uses the last occurrence.
If this is actually a use case for your code, replace `FirstOrDefault` with `LastOrDefault`.

Extending the code above, you can do something like this:

```
foreach(var tuple in forms.Select(x => new { Form = x,
                                             Definition = 
                                               formDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(y =>
                                                   x.SetupFormName.Contains(y.DESCR)) })
                          .Where(x => x.Definition != null))
{
    tuple.Form.SetupFormName = tuple.Definition.DESCR;
}
```

But as you can see, this gets messy real quick.

Comment: Note that this doesn't do the same thing - if there are two definitions where the latter is a substring of the former (e.g. abc and then ab) then the original code would reduce a SetupFormName of abcd to ab, whereas yours only reduces it to abc.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I know. Just wanted to edit a comment in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Note that you can use it if `formDefinitions` with suitable `DESCR` always exists.

```
forms.ForEach(f => f.SetupFormName = formDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(fd => 
    f.SetupFormName.Contains(fd.DESCR)).DESCR);
```

Comment: This will throw a NullReferenceException if there isn't a matching definition.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, that's why I wrote second sentence.

Comment: Your edit and my comment must have overlapped each other